# Nightmare page content not loading - Cannot assign to read only property 'onbeforeunload' of object '#<Window>'

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare

I'm using nightmare.js to make a bot that should perform the following tasks:

1. Go to facebook
2. Login into facebook
3. Go to marketplace
4. Make a marketplace publication

Once I get into fb and successfully login, no content is loaded except from the bluebar:

[image: error]

Nightmare uses electron, which's Devtools throws following errors:

[image: throwed error]

**Note** this is a self answered question, please, do not remove the answer. You may downvote it if, with some reasonable argument, you don´t agree  with it or have a better proposal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following this solution: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/1082#issuecomment-312115976

In your app folder, go to \node_modules\nightmare\lib\preload.js
Lines 50 and 55: change

```
writable: false,
```

to

```
writable: true,
```